# Central Motion with a Logarithmic potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, centripetal-force

A particle is moving under the influence of central force given by the potential:

$$V(r)=\alpha \log(r)$$

I have to calculate the radius of corresponding orbit in terms of L(angular momentum) and whether it is stable.

Assuming that alpha is positive and I differentiate the potential to get an extremum, it turns out there is none of real $L$. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Is it possible to have an extremum when it is moving in a circle? Force just acts perpendicularly with a constant magnitude.

Comment: I was just follwoing the logic that the orbit will be circular when E=Vmin

Comment: Apparently there is no Vmin

Comment: If $\alpha > 0$ then the particle always experiences a force pointing away from the centre of the field. With no centripetal force (like gravity or some other attractive force) no stable, bound orbits can exist.

Comment: @Gert The potential goes to zero as you go towards the center so there are bound states and the force is both radial and inwards.

Comment: @Timaeus: actually, the potential tend to $-\infty$ for $r \to 0$, right?

Comment: @Gert That is indeed what I meant to say, if you start more than a unit away and only move a little bit it is still true though, and the real point is that it decreases as you go inwards so it is an attractive potential.

Comment: @Timaeus: yes, so bound orbits are possible for $r<1$ but obviously not for $L=0$. Forgot about the basic nature of $\log r$ for a minute.

Comment: @Gert Every orbit is bound. Just like in a harmonic oscillator potential. And bound orbits are possible for L=0 just not circular orbits for L=0

Answer (score 3):

If you minimize the effective potential then you can force a circular orbit.

The effective potential only equals the potential when the angular momentum is zero.

What you have just shown is that there are no circular orbits when the angular momentum is zero.

You would get the same result if you used a $1/r$ central force potential.

Comment: Not that you can have a circular orbit with $L=0$... right?

Comment: @KyleOman What the OP showed is that there are no circular orbits when the angular momentum is zero.